# DatabaseConnecton issue in GRDB swift

Tags: ios, swift, grdb

I would like to use SQLite database in my iOS app and there are different frameworks available. So my current focus is on [GRDB](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift) and I have successfully created, inserted values, and received back with SQL commands as shown [here](http://groue.github.io/GRDB.swift/).

However, once the app is closed, how am I going to access the same `DataBaseQueue` and what should be the constant path to my database?

```
import GRDB

// Open a simple database connection

if let dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: "what should be the correct path ")!= nil{
    setupDatabase()
}
else
{
    dbQueue = DatabaseQueue()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GRDB FAQ](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/README.md#faq) answers your question:

> **How do I create a database in my application?**
>
> The database has to be stored in a valid place where it can be created and modified. For example, in the [Application Support directory](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html):
>
> ```
> let databaseURL = try FileManager.default
>     .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
>     .appendingPathComponent("db.sqlite")
> let dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: databaseURL.path)
> ```

Comment: ok so I didnot know that let dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: databaseURL.path) wasnt only used for retrieval of database, but it also creates one when there isnt available. Thankyou for the clarification sir

Comment: Yes, this is true. `DatabaseQueue(path:...)` creates the database if it does not exist yet, and opens it.

Comment: It's actually an SQLite feature, not a GRDB feature!